Why are the numbers in GEE download of MODIS AOD so different from usual MODIS AOD?
As I described (asked and later provided an answer) at Getting data to Drive or Cloud from GEE?  , I downloaded the mean Aerosol Optical Depth (AOD) values from MODIS using Google Earth Engine, GEE. The numbers I got are quite out of the AOD range (normally AOD should be a decimal number or maybe as high as 5 in extreme cases*), having numbers upto a few hundreds (371.2 etc) .
*The usual numbers can be seen here for example, prior to "extraction" of numbers by GEE from the visual MODIS AOD data: https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/?v=18.43332942184665,32.64054324972355,37.24346375507072,41.687584433419175&l=Reference_Labels_15m(hidden),Reference_Features_15m(hidden),Coastlines_15m,MODIS_Combined_MAIAC_L2G_AerosolOpticalDepth(hidden)
What could be the reason and how should I interpret the values I got?
The same situation appears to have occurred here: Download daily mean AOD data GEE
Thanks in advance,
Funda
